# Why did Maharishi Maitreya curse Duryodhana?

Tags: mahabharata, curse, duryodhana

It is known that Duryodhana was killed by Bhima during the Mahabharata war.

It is heard that a Maharishi named Maitreya, had infact ,cursed  Duryodhana, that he would be killed by Bhima,during the Mahabharata war.

Why did Maharishi Maitreya curse Duryodhana?

What are the details of the story?

Comment: It is heard? :D When u know the answer why don't u self-answer? It is allowed to do so.

Comment: Ok i thought if u have heard it u will also know about it. But then u may have to frame ur future Qs a bit differently. Because they give the impression that u already know the answers. Also when u have the preliminary idea of where the answer is to be found it's better to do lil bit of more search and answer urself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The detailed story can be found in [The Mahabharata, Book 3: Vana Parva: Aranyaka Parva: Section X](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03010.htm).

Maitreya on a pilgrimage to the different shrines, saw Yudhishthira in the woods of Kamyaka.

Later he visited Duryodhan and advised not to quarrel with the Pandavas.

But admonished by Maitreya,

> **Duryodhana began to slap his thigh resembling the trunk of the elephant**, and smilingly began to scratch the ground with his foot. And the wicked wretch spake not a word, but hung down his head.

By this Maitreya became angry and he set his mind upon cursing Duryodhana! And then, with eyes red in anger, Maitreya, touching water cursed Duryodhana as follows:

> Since, slighting me thou declinest to act according to my words, thou shalt speedily reap the fruit of this thy insolence! In the great war which shall spring out of the wrongs perpetrated by thee, **the mighty Bhima shall smash that thigh of thine with a stroke of his mace**!